# User submitted content

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a project that requires users to register, and submit details ( information on a company ). This need to take place on the front end rather than using the WordPress admin..

I have tried Gravity forms but it fails when I need to make edits to these submissions.

Is there a decent solution for modifying the users submitted content, or covering all aspects of this process?

One of the bigger issues has also been multiple file uploads and the option for premium listings.

Comment: At what point do you need to make edits to the submissions? I've done this with Gravity Forms and it worked for me. You do have to have the upgraded version so you can create posts directly from GF, but then you should be able to create a new post (with categories, custom fields etc) from GF and set its status to 'draft' so you can make edits before publishing.

Comment: Just to allow users to edit their submissions, Gravity forms is not properly repopulating the fields. 

Regular post data like title, and content show. None of the custom sections that I have added show up.

Comment: Ah - yes, agreed, Gravity Forms doesn't do that. I haven't had cause to explore this before but maybe one of these will work for you? http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/top-10-wordpress-plugins-for-front-end-posting-editing-and-uploading/

Comment: Do you know of a good way to assosiate all the form data with a post?

I had to use the latest 1.8 beta to give me multi file upload, but it seems that the Custom Post type add on had not been updated for about 2 years.

Comment: If that's not working, no sorry I don't. Have you tried the Gravity Forms forums? You'd think they'd have incorporated CPTs into the core by now, sheesh.

Comment: I just tried the latest version of GF and it seems to work with CPT, I was using a beta release. Im not sure if Editing was improved.